# How to compress the xml file at the time of Writing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I ave writing an XML File of size more than 1GB but at the time of writing I want to compress that file so that the size of an xml file is reduces so that at tile of `xmlDoc.Load(fileName)` load the file in minimum time duration.
my code for Writing an XML File is

```
 using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(_logFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    xmlDoc.Load(fileStream);
                    int byteLenght = fileStream.ReadByte();
                    byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteLenght);
                    intBytes = Compress(intBytes);
                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newelement);
                    fileStream.SetLength(0);
                    xmlDoc.Save(fileStream);
                }
```

also for compression

```
private static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] retVal;
            using (MemoryStream compressedMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                DeflateStream compressStream = new DeflateStream(compressedMemoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
                compressStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                compressStream.Close();
                retVal = new byte[compressedMemoryStream.Length];
                compressedMemoryStream.Position = 0L;
                compressedMemoryStream.Read(retVal, 0, retVal.Length);
                compressedMemoryStream.Close();
                compressStream.Close();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

but its not work for compression the file.

Comment: The simplest way will be to enable NTFS compression.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing the file on disk won't do much to improve the time spent loading the document, because the larger part of the time is in building up the object graph for the XmlDocument. It is so slow that it can take as long (or longer) as reading the uncompressed XML from disk. Although compression can save time here, it's only a minor gain if a fast media like an internal hdd is used.

If you want to improve performance working with large XML files, you'll need to use something like an XmlReader that streams the file instead of loading it all at once.

Comment: -1 because completely wrong: disk access and in-memory operations (either decompression or building the object graph) are not at the same scale. Any compression (NTFS/gzip/[lzo](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) etc) is faster than nothing. Remember [this metaphor about heart beats](https://gist.github.com/hellerbarde/2843375#file-latency_humanized-markdown). However I agree that streaming is essential at that size scale.

Comment: I'm not sure how the difference in speed between disk access and in memory operations corresponds to a difference in how long it takes to load the entire file into memory and call `xmlDoc.load` based on using file compression.

Comment: By feeding xmlDoc.Load() with a DeflateStream which in turn reads from the FileStream (that stores compressed XML), the same amount of data will appear in the memory with much less disk I/O (XML usually compresses very well). In other words you can load the entire file into memory much faster: the cost of decompression is dwarfed by
the cost of disk I/O. The savings must be clearly noticeable because
disk I/O is sooo slow compared to working in-memory. (Except when the RAM is not enough for xmlDoc.Load() and thus the OS has to swap a lot. The disk I/O of such trashing dominate everything.)

Comment: This assumes that the majority of the cost of calling xmlDoc.load is reading the buffer into memory. I doubt that that's the case, but I don't have a .NET environment readily available to test it. I would expect loading the data into an Xml object graph with potentially hundreds of thousands of .Net objects to completely dwarf the cost of the disk I/O. Have you tested this w/ > 1GB files and seen meaningful increases in performance?

Comment: I remembered that I had a Windows VM so I threw together a quick test. I didn't see the behavior you describe whereby the disk I/O would dwarf the cost of building the object graph. At most I saw a ~4 percent decrease in load times w/ compression and in some cases loading the compressed file was slower. Was there a flaw in my test?https://gist.github.com/gerrard00/1a2584adcc84163f4d8cc69e40022092

Comment: _“This assumes that the majority of the cost of calling xmlDoc.load is reading the buffer into memory”_ – exactly. This has nothing to do with the .NET environment, this is because reading into memory means reading from some media/device, and that's where the majority of the cost is. Thanks for the gist, I commented there, too

Comment: I replied as well. I don't think you can ignore the .NET environment which has to load multiple gigabytes of data into an object graph containing hundreds of thousands of nodes when looking at the overall cost of the operation. Everyone knows disk access is much slower than memory access. The question is, does that difference dwarf any possible work you do after loading the data into your process. I don't think it does and I'd love to see a test that shows your assertion to be true.